# Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, regression, mass

I'm trying to run ordered logit regression using the mass package and I keep coming up with this error message in R.
I'm running the model

`fit2 <- polr(level ~ pvi + enrollment, data = schools, Hess = TRUE)`
`summary(fit2)`

But this gives me the error `Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'`

If I run the same model with just level and pvi I don't get any errors. Enrollment is an integer variable that goes from about 50-50,000 and there's no missing data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dividing enrollment by say 100 and then re-run the model.
I tried doing that in my case and it helped.

Comment: Provide a sample data using `dput`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).